# How to configure datetimepicker to work correctly when only the date is selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- XDSoft DateTimePicker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<body>
   <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >

   <script>
      jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        minDate: 0, // today
        minTime: 0, // now
        defaultSelect: false,
        inline: true,   
      });
   </script>
</body>
```

- The problem is that when I **only** select the date, datetimepicker
  gets initialized with **current** time passing the validation, which I don't want because I'm
  using 60min default step and also because it's counterintuitive since
  I didn't select any time ( nor one it's selected by default - which is fine ).
- Any ideas on how I can make it work properly when submitting the form? I would like to stick
  with the inlined version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used datetimepicker before however I messed around with it and think I have something like what you're asking for. First I wrapped your script in a `$(document).ready()` as this is recommended so the page loads correctly.

I then added your input and a button to a form element so we can submit the form and identify it via a form id. I commented out the `minTime: 0`  as it greys out hours before the current hour even on future dates. I then added an array for the `allowTimes` property with hourly intervals (you can update how you like). Although I now don't see a time being highlighted automatically once a date is chosen, it seems to be automatically choosing the current time. To get around this I added a boolean **onTimeChosen** that becomes true only when the user selects a time.

That with a simple if statement means the user can't progress unless they've selected a time.

```
<body>
    
    <form id="myForm">
        <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" required>
        <button type="submit" id="form-submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            
            let onTimeChosen = false;

            jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                minDate: 0, // today
                // minTime: 0, // now
                defaultSelect: false,
                inline: true,  
                datetimepicker: false,
                onSelectTime: function() {
                    onTimeChosen = true;
                },
                allowTimes:[
                    '00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00',
                    '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00',
                    '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00',
                    '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'
                    ],
                
            });
            
            $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
               
                if(!onTimeChosen){
                    alert("You need to select a time");
                    event.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    var d = $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('getValue');
                    alert(d.toDateString());
                }
            })
        });

       
    </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting future hours list automatically:

```
...
allowTimes: generateTimes(new Date()),
onChangeDateTime: logic,
...
function generateTimes(date) {
  var result = [];
  var nowHour = date.getHours();

  for(var i = nowHour + 1; i < 24; i++){
    result.push(i + ":00");
  }
  return result;
}

function generateAllTimes() {
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++){
    result.push(i + ":00");
  }
  return result;
}

var logic = function(currentDateTime)
{
    var date = new Date();
    if(currentDateTime.getDate() == (date.getDate()))
    {
        this.setOptions
        ({
            allowTimes: generateTimes(new Date()),
        });
    }
    else
    {
        this.setOptions
        ({
            allowTimes: generateAllTimes(),
        });
    }    
}
```